# Navigation mobile sobre o content page

Tags: html, css

Criei um navigation mobile, onde ele se expande ao clicar na logo do meu site. Porém ele está expandido no conteúdo da minha página. Gostaria que ele expandisse por cima do conteúdo, de forma que cobrisse todo conteúdo da página. Já tentei de todas as formas, o width dele já está 100%.

```html
<div class="nav-mobile">
    <div class="nav-mobile__container">
        <ul class="nav-mobile__links">
            {% for link in linklists[linklist].links %}
            <li class="navigation__entrance-animation  navigation__entrance-animation--active">
                <a href="{{ link.url }}">
                    {{ link.title | escape }}
                </a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
.nav-mobile {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-out;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}

.nav-mobile__container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}


.nav-mobile__links {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.navigation__entrance-animation.navigation__entrance-animation--active,
.navigation-open--editor .navigation__entrance-animation {
    max-height: 1001px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.navigation__entrance-animation {
    transition: max-height 0.01s, transform 0.25s ease-out, opacity 0.25s ease-out;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
}

.navigation__entrance-animation a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--color_nav_mobile);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'CarosSoftRegular';
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na hora que fizer o trigger para abrir o menu vc coloca position fixed nele com top 0

Comment: então eu gostaria que cobrisse o conteúdo e não o header, saca?

Comment: Então da um `top` com o mesmo valor do height do header... Cara edita sua pergunta e coloca o mínimo de código que de para simular o seu problema, ai facilita para te responder

Comment: foi mal mano, sou mei confuso msm mas acho que deu bom: position: fixed;
    height: 100%;